# Style the root element of an AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an AngularJS directive which is used in "Element" mode i.e. it is used as a custom tag in HTML.

```
angular
    .module('myModule')
    .directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                attr1: '=',
                attr2: '='
            },
            ...
        };
    });
```

When I use this directive, AngularJS creates a root element `<my-directive>` to contain all the elements inside the directive template. This element is visible in the browser debugger (Firebug or Chrome debugger).

How do I apply a style to this root element? If I put a `style` or `class` attribute directly on the `<my-directive>` tag, it is ignored by the browser.

```
<my-directive attr1="val1" attr2="val2"
              style="...styles for root element (ignored)..."
              class="...alternate method (also ignored)...">
</my-directive>
```

Currently, I am using the directive `link` function to add in those styles, as shown here: [How to manipulate styles of directive in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246110/how-to-manipulate-styles-of-directive-in-angularjs).

However, these styles may not be related to the logic of the directive. They may even change based on how/where the directive is used. Some examples (off the top of my head):

- Styles for external positioning, for example, `float: left`
- Styles for element background - think alternating row colors in a grid
- etc.

So they do not belong inside the directive. How do I declare these styles from outside the directive? The styles need to be "per instance", not a single common style for all `my-directive`s.

I'm using AngularJS 1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Note:

After further research, it turns out that my question was based on a misunderstanding. Most styles are in fact correctly applied when used in a `style` attribute on the root directive element. For example, the attributes mentioned in the question, `background-color` and `float` are actually applied correctly to the root directive element.

My specific issue was with the `height` and `width` style attributes. It turns out that the same thing happens in other scenarios, so it does not seem to be specific to AngularJS or directives.

Since there have been no upvoted/correct answers up to this point, I am closing out the question with this clarification (marked as **community wiki**).

See [How to handle your own obsolete/incorrect questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237598/how-to-handle-your-own-obsolete-incorrect-questions) for further discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS like this

my-directive {
background: red;
}

Comment: If you look at my examples, the styles need to be per-instance. This may work for common styling, but not individual instances. I've edited the question to add in the clarification.

Comment: You'll need to add a class in that case, and style each class accordingly.

Comment: Right.. but then we circle back to the same question: Where do I assign the class? The `class` attribute is ignored just like the `style` attribute :)

Comment: It depends when you can determine the class.  If you can determine it before the directive gets rendered, you could use ng-class on <my-directive>.

Comment: Interesting! I will have to try that out. Does ng-style also work then?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the CSS post rendering, then you can use the jqLite `css()` on the `element`:

```
angular
    .module('myModule')
    .directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                attr1: '=',
                attr2: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs)
            {
                element.css('background-color', 'red');
            }
        };
    });
```

This is jqLite and is supported by AngularJS without jQuery library included.

Comment: I'm trying to do this **outside** the directive. My linked question already shows this method, but I'd like to keep it independent.

Comment: @metacubed, well, the correct angular method would be that outside of your directive you somehow raise a flag within this directive, and this directive will change the css. Remember that in Angular, each directive should only modify itself. if others want to modify another directive, then you need to modify the directive at hand somehow, and perform the operation.

Comment: The styles I talk about have nothing to do with the directive. They are purely composition-related, such as using "float:left". They are also different per-instance. Why would the directive know about these?